# Data-dump for ServerFault?

Tags: feature-request

Is there any plans for a data-dump for ServerFault? (Or more importantly meta.stackoverflow?)

Answer (score 8):

<s>We will do this, but I agree with Michael -- there's not enough data yet. Plus, we'd like to "perfect" the process with the SO data dump before extending it to the other sites.</s>

See the latest SO blog entry for plans.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-09/

Comment: It's been nearly 2 months since this answer was posted. Any updates?

Comment: Hey Jeff, just curious if you've got a timeframe in mind for this!  There are some stats I'd like to compile :)

Comment: I've opened up a feature request to discuss this again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23615/include-all-sites-in-future-data-dumps

Comment: Any updates on the SU and SF data dumps?

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you'd need a lot more data for it to be worthwhile, but I guess once we get to that point it's likely to happen...

Comment: May as well start somewhere (SF does have about 7k questions just now). It shouldn't be much extra work to do a data-dump of a smaller site. Plus it'd be nice to have a smaller set of data to work with, for setting up scripts and the likes (rather than working with > 1.2GB of data)